# go to function when press button in JS form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I created Form in JS and react, when user press the button "submit" I want it to trigger the function "submit" and pass all the values from the form.
how can I do it?

```
import React from 'react';

export default function MessageForm(){

    const submit = (values) => {
        console.log(values);
    }

    return(
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 tm-flex-center-v tm-section-left">
                <form action="http://localhost:3001/messaging/write-message" class="tm-contact-form" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <input type="text" id="sender" name="sender" class="form-control" placeholder="From" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <input type="text" id="receiver" name="receiver" class="form-control" placeholder="To" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-4">
                        <textarea rows="1" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject..." required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-6">
                        <textarea rows="5" id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message..." required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-0 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" onClick="submit" class="btn tm-btn-primary tm-send-btn">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 tm-circle-img-container tm-contact-right">
                <img src="../img/img-01.jpg" alt="message" class="rounded-circle tm-circle-img"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `onClick={submit}` instead of `onClick="submit"`. Pass the actual function itself rather than a string with the function name. The callback will recieve a parameter `event`, not `values` though. You'll probably need to store all of the individual form values in state using controlled components. See [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`just replace "submit" with {submit} in the button tag onClick attribute <button type="submit" onClick={submit} class="btn tm-btn-primary tm-send-btn">Send</button>`

Comment: but After I did it, every time I press submit, it refresh the page